# Library disappeared from UI but UNC path still working

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, office-365

One of my libraries just disappeared. It wasn't deleted, it's not in the recycle bin, it's not in the site contents and I can no longer access it through the path. However, I had mapped the library to my desktop in order to push files to it for my testing, the mapping still works, the files are still there etc.

Never seen this before. This is on Office 365.

Answer (score 2):

Using SharePoint Designer 2013, open the site (e.g. `https://companyName.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName`). In Designer, go to `Lists and Libraries` on the left hand navigation pane. Find the Library in question and click on it. Is `Hide from browser` checked? If so, uncheck it.

Comment: Hey, it doesn't show up there either